# number of zero days in a row field

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe like the input column below.  It has a date column "dates" and a int column "qty".  I would like to create a new column "daysout" that has the difference in days between the current date value and the first consecutive date where qty=0.  I've provided example input and output below.  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

input df:

```
dates      qty
2020-04-01 1
2020-04-02 0
2020-04-03 0
2020-04-04 3
2020-04-05 0
2020-04-06 7
```

output:

```
dates      qty daysout
2020-04-01 1   0
2020-04-02 0   0
2020-04-03 0   1
2020-04-04 3   2
2020-04-05 0   0
2020-04-06 7   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach which compares if current row is 0 and lagged row is not 0 , then takes a sum of that window , which then acts as a window for a row number to be assigned and subtract 1 to get your desired result:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

w = Window().partitionBy().orderBy(F.col("dates"))
w1 = F.sum(F.when((F.col("qty")==0)&(F.lag("qty").over(w)!=0),1).otherwise(0)).over(w)
w2 = Window.partitionBy(w1).orderBy('dates')
```

---

```
df.withColumn("daysout",F.row_number().over(w2) - 1).show()

+----------+---+-------+
|     dates|qty|daysout|
+----------+---+-------+
|2020-04-01|  1|      0|
|2020-04-02|  0|      0|
|2020-04-03|  0|      1|
|2020-04-04|  3|      2|
|2020-04-05|  0|      0|
|2020-04-06|  7|      1|
+----------+---+-------+
```